# Lenovo ideapad 500-15acz wireless card is not recognized

Tags: wireless, 15.10, lenovo

I installed ubuntu 15.10 onto my new laptop that normally runs windows 10 and I cant get ubuntu to recognize that the wireless card exists at all. The windows 10 driver is called Atheros WLAN Driver 7.35.295.2. I have tried a few things from various blogs but i cant get anything to work.

> lspci | grep -i wireless

returns nothing.

> lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1576
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1577
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] 
Carrizo (rev c5)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP 
Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1578
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157d
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157a
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 49)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4a)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1570
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1571
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1572
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1573
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1574
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1575
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 43ae (rev 02)
```

> lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ae] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0622]
```

> iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.
```

> rfkill

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I am not sure what all to try. I know the wireless card works because it works on the windows partition.
Any help please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: The post was edited, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have good news for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this adapter `Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ae] (rev 02)` is not supported by Linux or Broadcom proprietary drivers yet.

Comment: That the conclusion I came to but I am no expert. I was hoping I missed something.

Comment: There are some open-source and proprietary drivers that support Broadcom adapters. None of them support this one.

Comment: I hope situation will improve with 16.04.